# Cannot delete or update a parent row Even though the SQL statement alters the table first

Tags: php, mysql

SQL/PHP Error:

We are supposed to create a website and link it to the database and in one of the web pages, we have the delete form to delete a menu item based on the item number. The webpage is linked to a database and it is supposed to delete a menu item from all the tables that contain the item which are the menu table and the order_menu table; But it is not doing it, I dont know if I have syntax error or if I am doing something wrong. Here is what I have so far:

Error:

```
Error deleting record: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`MENUDB`.`ORDER_MENU`, CONSTRAINT `ORDER_MENU_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Item_Number`) REFERENCES `MENU` (`Item_Number`))
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include 'project_header.php'; ?>
<body>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename = "MENUDB";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
die("Connection/fatal failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "ALTER TABLE ORDER_MENU DROP CONSTRAINT ref_to_menu, DROP INDEX ref_to_menu;";
$sql = "ALTER TABLE ORDER_MENU ADD CONSTRAINT ref_to_menu FOREIGN KEY(Item_Number) REFERENCES MENU(Item_Number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;";

$sql = "DELETE FROM MENU WHERE Item_Number='" . $_GET["Item_Number"] . "'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
$conn->close();

?>


</body>
<?php include 'project_footer.php'; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't executing the altering SQL statements. You are just overwriting the `$sql` variable and in the end you try to execute the last one (the `DELETE`).

Comment: and how can I execute it!!

Comment: You're already executing (calling `mysqli_query`), but you need to do it after every statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As El_Vanja said you're overwriting the queries with successive assignments to `$sql`.

You could solve this by appending them, assigning them to an array or calling them sequentially. I will append as that's likely the best way as it only call the DB once.

Note the second and third queries are `$sql .=`  not `$sql =` note the extra `.` this will concatenate the new string to the old.

It's also worth noting **THIS CODE IS NOT SAFE** as it concatenates straight posted data into your database. I highly recommend you look into using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and binding the parameters. I have added [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) which is fine, but not as good as PDO.

```php
$sql = "ALTER TABLE ORDER_MENU DROP CONSTRAINT ref_to_menu, DROP INDEX ref_to_menu;";
$sql .= "ALTER TABLE ORDER_MENU ADD CONSTRAINT ref_to_menu FOREIGN KEY(Item_Number) REFERENCES MENU(Item_Number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;";
$sql .= "DELETE FROM MENU WHERE Item_Number='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["Item_Number"]) . "'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

$conn->close();
```